# Copy formula to entire column in excel without dragging bottom right of a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel file, which has 300 rows, 500 columns, and I apply a formula to one cell in one of the columns, the formula is to calculate the sum of the elements of the specific row (name is the first column, I store the sum in the 2nd column, and the sum calculation begins from the 3rd column), now I want to apply the same formula to each cell of the column, one way to achieve this, is by dragging the bottom right of the cell, but since the file has 300 rows, so this way takes a lot of time, is there an easier way to achieve the same?

Comment: Use a table >> Insert - Table from the ribbon. If you enter a formula into one column it will expand automaticall to the whole column

Comment: Try double clicking on the autofill handle, this is the same part of the cell that you use to drag down. If there are no gaps or anomalies in the rest of the corresponding cells then it should autofill to the last row. Otherwise as previously mentioned, use tables.

Comment: I created a table, but how do I freeze what used to be the top row, as it is the second row now, it contains dates, so I need to freeze it to fill the entries

Comment: was able to freeze also, thanks